# How to SOQL Email Conversation from EAC

Tags: soql, email, einstein-activity-capture

Can I make a select to obtain information from these emails (activities) from Einstein Activity Capture or just using "view full email"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) object to see the details of the outbound communication.

```
SELECT FromAddress, Status, Subject, TextBody, ToAddress FROM EmailMessage
```

I suggest you modify the field list to capture the data points you need from the object but more importantly, add a filter to this SOQL as the table for this object can grow exponentially. `RelatedToId` is a candidate for filtering.

Comment: I appreciate your reply but EmailMessage did not serve what I need and it was my fault for not adding this detail. Sending is being done through Einstein Activity Capture and EmailMessage does not keep this.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I haven't verified it, but you should be able to use the Tableau CRM REST API to query, with SAQL, the Emails stored in the Activities Tableau CRM Dashboard.

See Salesforce help on the Activity Dashboard included with EAC: [Review the Activities Dashboard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.aac_review_activity_reports.htm&type=5)

See Tableau CRM REST API: [Query Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_query.htm)

A sample POST body response will look like this, per SF Documentation:
Example SAQL Response Body (without metadata)

```
{
  "action":"query",
  "responseId":"3vy-E9YmX-TIWe0769juD-",
  "results": {
    "records":[
      {"FirstName":"","count":1},
      {"FirstName":"Admin","count":1},
      {"FirstName":"Integration","count":1},
      {"FirstName":"Security","count":1}
    ]
  },
  "query":"q = load \"0Fbxx0000000006CAA/0Fcxx000000001dCAA\";
           q = group q by 'FirstName';
           q = foreach q generate 'FirstName' as 'FirstName', count() as 'count';
           q = limit q 2000;",
  "responseTime":544
}
```